# Dynamically render data in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, render

This is a typical route in node.js that has a **pseudo-code** to connect to a database, get some data using a query and then pass them to a page to be rendered,

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
  db-connect(function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log('error');
    }
    db.query('select * from table', function(err, results){
        if (err) {
          return console.log('error');
        }
        res.render('index',{
            'title':'my title',
            'pageHeader': 'my header',
            'results': results //dynamic ???
        });
    });
  }); //connect
});//router get
```

I am using this pseudo-code to ask a general question :

The `results` data are dynamic,  maybe the query will take a while, so the `results` do not get to the page fast, so I guess the rendering will also take a while.

How can I render static data immediatly (`title` and `pageHeader`) and the dynamic part (`results`) as soon as it is ready ?

Do I have to use another function or another syntax?

Thank you

Comment: Request and populate the results over AJAX.

Comment: ```res.render``` populates your template and sends it to the browser.

Answer (score 1):

`res.render` populates your template and sends it to the client (browser). You cannot send "a bit more" when it's ready at a later stage.

Either make the client wait for the data, or send your title and header first, and use XHR (javascript) on the browser to get the rest.